# Using a ForeignKey in a mixin

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I am trying to store graph traces and their sequences in 2 separate tables with sqlalchemy.

A list of traces on the same graph are stored in the ListContainer table.  Each ListItem represents an item in the trace. Each trace item has a foreign key to its trace as I want to note it's position in the trace.

This is my current code:

```
#store traces
class ListContainer():
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        # timestamp = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now())
        name = Column(String)
#endclass

#store flow in traces
class ListItem():
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        @declared_attr
        trace_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(ListContainer.id))
        item_pos = Column(Integer)
        #start_ea
        #end-ea
#endclass

class Trace(Base, ListContainer):
        __tablename__="trace_table"


class TraceItem(Base, ListItem):
        __tablename__="trace_items"
        start_ea = Column(String)
```

However, I'm currently getting the following error:

```
    trace_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(ListContainer.id))
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the correct way to add a ForeignKey to a table using a mixin class?

Comment: @thank you for the edits, sorry had a long day and was desperate when I approached SO, thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only decorate functions, so that's where the syntax error is coming from.

If you [follow the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html?highlight=mixin#mixing-in-columns), you will see that a foreign key in a mixin should be contained in a decorated function.

```
class ListItem(object):
    # ...

    @declared_attr
    def trace_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey(ListContainer.id))

    # ...
```